# Navigate to store front from admin

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

Trying to figure out how to view the storefront from the admin portal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such ability in magento admin panel.

Just edit the URL in address bar. Remove all starting from /admin ( or /[customadminpath] - if you change admin url during installation)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access it via CMS --> Pages --> Home Page --> Preview. However editing the URL as the previous poster mentioned is quicker/easier.